# Rsync skip folder based on wildcard

Tags: rsync

Script:

```
ash-4.4# cat rsync-backup.sh
    #!/bin/sh
    # Usage: rsync-backup.sh <src> <dst> <label>
    if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "$0: Expected 3 arguments, received $#: $@" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if [ -d "$2/__prev/" ]; then
        rsync -azP --delete --link-dest="$2/__prev/" "$1" "$2/$3"
    else
        rsync -azP                                   "$1" "$2/$3"
    fi
    rm -f "$2/__prev"
    ln -s "$3" "$2/__prev"
```

How can I change this that it skip specific folders based on a wildcard?

This folder should be skipped always:

```
home/forge/*/storage/framework/cache/* 
home/forge/*/vendor
home/forge/*/node_modules
```

But how can this be achieved? What to change in the original `rsync-backup.sh` file?

This is not working:

`rsync -azP "$1" "$2/$3" --exclude={'node_modules', 'cache','.cache','.npm','vendor','.git'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--exclude={'dir1','dir2',...}` does not work under `sh` shell.  It works only under `bash`.

Your options are:

1. use `bash`, then the `--exclude={'node_modules', 'cache','.cache','.npm','vendor','.git'}` will work.
2. use multiple `--exclude` switches like: `--exclude=` statements. For example, `rsync <params> --exclude='node_modules' --exclude='cache' --exclude='.cache' ...`
3. use `--exclude-from`, where you have a text file with list of excluded directories.  Like:

`rsync <params> --exclude-from='/home/user/excluded_dir_list.txt' ...`

The file `excluded_dir_list.txt` would contain one excluded dir for line like:

```
node_modules
cache
.cache
.npm
vendor
.git
```